# how can I change the size of particles?

Tags: particles

I am fairly new to blender, and I am wondering how to change the size of the particles I am working with. They are way to big. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This can be changed in the particle settings under either *Physics* or *Render* (when using a display type that allows this) with the *Size* slider. You can also change the size of your particle objects by scaling the main object(s) you are using but it's best to control the size via the particle settings.

Additionally, you can randomize the size of your particles by using the *Random Size* slider.

[image]