# Change size of particles in old "laser particle" example?

Tags: particles

I have found [Laser beam pathway with reflective mirrors](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39663/laser-beam-pathway-with-reflective-mirrors) - and I would like to run the example there: [image]

Unfortunately, this is an example from some years ago, and I use Blender 2.92; so when I click Bake, and then click Play as recommended, I get this:

[image]

I guess those massive balls in the screenshot should be small particles? In any case, they seem to be not selectable with the mouse...

So I found [how can I change the size of particles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5483/how-can-i-change-the-size-of-particles) - but that question is even older, and I have no "size" under Physics.

So, how can I control the size of the particles in that example in Blender 2.92?

Comment: Those are Billboard particles, and are not renderable in modern version of Blender as far as I know, so even if you managed to changed their size I don't think It would help you much

Comment: Thanks @DuarteFarrajotaRamos - never heard of Billboard particles before, but it makes sense ... Feel free to post this as an answer, I'll accept it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well...you can fake it...like this:

Turn gravity off, insert an emitter with just one vertex, insert some planes with collision and you get:

[image]

I am using a sphere as object here and give it some emission color.

Blend file:
[image]

With some HDRI and Bloom turned on:

[image]

Comment: I'll avoid the bins in the Bahnhof from now on.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the workaround and the example .blend file!

Comment: glad i could help.